# How to achieve smooth camera movement from mouse input

Tags: c++, 3d, game-engine, glfw

Alright, so I've been trying to figure this out for several years now (no joke, i'll work on it until I can't anymore and move onto another task telling myself i'll come back to it later and it's been a never ending loop), but I think I've finally collected enough information about what's going on that I can explain with enough detail that someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

The issue is that I cannot seem to achieve a smooth camera rotation based off mouse input in this 3d framework/engine I've been working on (hobby project) with c++/glfw/glad/opengl. I've gone through and made sure that within windows mouse acceleration is disabled, within glfw cursor is disabled and GLFW_RAW_MOUSE_MOTION is enabled. There is nothing (that i'm aware of) that should be skewing the mouse input values that are being obtained.

The below is debug output I generated which shows: `frame_time|current_mouse_x_position|mouse_delta_for_tick`

```
0.010011: 5803.000000: 9.000000
0.010001: 5810.000000: 7.000000
0.010011: 5819.000000: 9.000000
0.010002: 5836.000000: 17.000000
0.010011: 5845.000000: 9.000000
0.010001: 5854.000000: 9.000000
0.010001: 5861.000000: 7.000000
0.010015: 5876.000000: 15.000000
0.010002: 5884.000000: 8.000000
0.010002: 5894.000000: 10.000000
0.010264: 5902.000000: 8.000000
0.010009: 5919.000000: 17.000000
0.010010: 5928.000000: 9.000000
0.010011: 5935.000000: 7.000000
0.010006: 5943.000000: 8.000000
0.010010: 5958.000000: 15.000000
0.010090: 5965.000000: 7.000000
0.010005: 5971.000000: 6.000000
0.010013: 5979.000000: 8.000000
0.010042: 5994.000000: 15.000000
0.010012: 6001.000000: 7.000000
0.010004: 6009.000000: 8.000000
0.010009: 6016.000000: 7.000000
0.010007: 6033.000000: 17.000000
```

This data was collected while moving the mouse along the x-axis as consistently as my hand would allow, and you can see in the `mouse_delta_for_tick` column that every so often the values appear to be double what they should be.

My first thought was that this could be due to the amount of time between when the positions are sampled, but you can see in the first column that the frame_time stays relatively consistent. So I'm uncertain what could be causing these values to be so off.

You can imagine that when using these values to calculate the camera rotation, it becomes stuttery/clicky. Below is how I'm doing the update every tick:

```
void Client::updateMouseDelta()
{
    // this->input updated elsewhere as fast as engine can update it, so in this function it is
    // the current mouse position for this tick
    this->currentMousePosition.x = this->input.mouseXPos;
    this->currentMousePosition.y = this->input.mouseYPos;

    if (this->firstMouseInput)
    {
        this->lastMousePosition = this->currentMousePosition;
        this->firstMouseInput = false;
    }

    //TODO mousedelta calculation and framerate or something causing noisy deltas??????idk????
    this->mouseDelta.x = this->currentMousePosition.x - this->lastMousePosition.x;
    this->mouseDelta.y = this->lastMousePosition.y - this->currentMousePosition.y;

    this->lastMousePosition = this->currentMousePosition;
}

void Client::updatePitchYaw()
{
    this->yaw += this->mouseDelta.x * this->mouseSensitivity;
    this->pitch += this->mouseDelta.y * this->mouseSensitivity;

    // make sure that when pitch is out of bounds, screen doesn't get flipped
    if (this->pitch > 89.0f)
        this->pitch = 89.0f;
    if (this->pitch < -89.0f)
        this->pitch = -89.0f;
}

void Client::updateRotation(float frameTime, float renderLerpInterval)
{
    this->updateMouseDelta();
    this->updatePitchYaw();

    this->lookDirection.x = cos(glm::radians(this->yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(this->pitch));
    this->lookDirection.y = sin(glm::radians(this->pitch));
    this->lookDirection.z = sin(glm::radians(this->yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(this->pitch));
    this->lookDirection = glm::normalize(this->lookDirection);

    auto cameraPosition = this->ccc->getCapsuleActor()->getInterpolatedTranslation(renderLerpInterval);

    this->worldCamera->setPosition(cameraPosition);
    this->worldCamera->setLookAt(cameraPosition + this->lookDirection);
}
```

I've done various things throughout the years to attempt to mask this stutter by smoothing the input, but it's never perfect and always introduces a noticeable latency in mouse movement (moving average filter, converting into a quaternion and using slerp between previous and current rotations, a low pass filter (although that might have been a different unrelated issue now that I think about it)).

Also just to double confirm that this wasn't unrelated to mouse input I implemented a simple rotation test using arrow keys as such (which is buttery smooth):

```
void Client::updatePitchYaw()
{
    if (this->input.keyUp)
        this->pitch += 0.75f;
    if (this->input.keyDown)
        this->pitch -= 0.75f;

    if (this->input.keyRight)
        this->yaw += 0.75f;
    if (this->input.keyLeft)
        this->yaw -= 0.75f;

    // make sure that when pitch is out of bounds, screen doesn't get flipped
    if (this->pitch > 89.0f)
        this->pitch = 89.0f;
    if (this->pitch < -89.0f)
        this->pitch = -89.0f;
}
```

If you've made it this far THANK YOU, and I suppose my main question is: How can I achieve the sort of buttery smooth responsive camera rotation via mouse input that every other game I've ever played seems to be able to achieve (counter-strike, quake3, half-life, etc)? There MUST be something that I'm missing.

**EDIT**

Adding main gameloop code and mouse input update code (stripped down version of loop, but all relevant parts should be there) which should make it clear how I am getting the mouse position values:

```
/*
App::execute() invoked via main(), once invoked, this method controls the
application until it is terminated.
*/
void App::execute()
{
    this->fixedLogicTime = 1 / this->config.LOGIC_TICK; // LOGIC_TICK = 120.0
    this->currentTime = this->time();

    while (true)
    {

        if (this->shouldClose || this->window->shouldClose())
            break;

        this->newTime = this->time();
        this->frameTime = this->newTime - this->currentTime;
        
        // UPDATE MOUSE INPUT HERE. THIS METHOD CALLS THE Window::setMouse() method
        // which is included below this one
        this->window->updateInputState();
        

        if (this->frameTime >= (1 / this->config.MAX_RENDER_FPS)) // cap max fps
        {
            this->currentTime = this->newTime;              

            if (this->frameTime > 0.25)
                this->frameTime = 0.25;

            this->accumulator += this->frameTime;

            while (this->accumulator >= this->fixedLogicTime)
            {
                this->activeScene->applyTransformations();
                this->activeScene->processSensors();
                this->activeScene->innerLoop((float)this->fixedLogicTime); // fixed logic updates
                this->activeScene->updateAnimations(this->fixedLogicTime);
                this->activeScene->stepPhysics((float)this->fixedLogicTime);
                this->activeScene->postPhysics((float)this->fixedLogicTime);
                this->accumulator -= this->fixedLogicTime;
            }
            
            float renderLerpInterval = (float)(this->accumulator / this->fixedLogicTime);
            
            // THIS METHOD WOULD BE CALLING THE METHODS WHERE THE MOUSE INPUT VALUES ARE USED
            // IE, MY PREVIOUSLY POSTED Client::updateRotation() METHOD
            this->activeScene->outerLoop((float)this->frameTime, renderLerpInterval); // immediate logic updates
            
            this->gpu->clearBuffers(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            this->activeScene->draw(renderLerpInterval);
        }
    }
}

void Window::setMouse() 
{
    double mXPos;
    double mYPos;

    glfwGetCursorPos(this->glfwWindow, &mXPos, &mYPos);

    this->inputState.mouseXPos = (float)mXPos;
    this->inputState.mouseYPos = (float)mYPos;
}
```

Comment: I would start with how exactly are you getting the mouse position values? You certainly should be getting 1 pixel precision if you sample frequently enough.

Comment: must be an issue with the input - your desktop mouse cursor doesn't jump either.

Comment: @Quimby I have made an edit to include code which shows how I am obtaining the mouse position values (see comments in code)

Answer (score 1):

You get smooth rotation with key press, because you add (subtract) a fixed value from the previous/actual one and increase (decrease) the rotation by a fixed amount. Every frame shows you a rotation by a fixed angle (smooth).

If you want to achieve the same result as key presses, use the same method.

Divide the screen into cells (the cell size is determined by your scaling factor, e.g. how many key strokes it needs for 180 degrees, which is equal to the screen width or a mouse motion from left to right). Based on your mouse position or moved distance, calculate the cell your pointer resides within or how many cells it moved, which gives you in return the desired angle for the rotation (by a fixed amount, just like key strokes).

Therefore, small changes of the mouse pointer will have no effect, only if the moved distance is greater than a cell size, then a rotation will occur (moved cells multiplied by a scaling factor).

Comment: This is intriguing. Is this something that is commonly implemented to handle smooth mouse rotation?

Comment: I honestly don't know if that is the common method. It was just an idea of mine, on how to avoid rotation, if you moved your mouse just by one or two pixels. Normally, some (spline) interpolation method would be the more appropriate choice to smoothen a curve (set of points).

Comment: This is entirely equivalent to do a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of the delta, with extra complicated steps involved.

Comment: @YSC I don't think so, this seems more a quantization with a threshold, it introduces an hysteresis on the input

Comment: @MatG you might be right. I see this method being efficient to filter noise only if the pointer stays within a cell though, making its trajectory a random walk. The mean of a random walk is zero you'd notice.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I finally figured it out, and it is so soul crushingly simple I'm almost embarrassed to post this answer, BUT maybe it will help someone down the road...

It was the mouse :(

I have multiple machines that I work from. Recently I have been using my laptop with [this mouse](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02576082) and this is where I started noticing the stutter again. However, before I jumped to the conclusion that it was something code related, I tested the exact same build on my standing desktop setup, which also uses an hp mouse similar to the one above but not exact, and the issue persisted. This acted as my confirmation that something wasn't right since it was happening on both systems.

This evening, thinking it was something performance related I jumped on my primary desktop (5900x, rtx3070, etc), which uses a razer lancehead mouse...and the rotation was perfectly smooth. I then grabbed both of the hp mice and tried each on this system, and wouldn't you know...it was a stuttery mess.

I'm willing to accept this as the problem to the issue, but I had used that hp mouse  on my last primary desktop build for years and played countless games and never noticed any of this stutteriness, I mean it's a 1000dpi mouse which should be plenty sensitive enough. I'm wondering if there is something that changed with the windows 10 usb mouse drivers? That's really all I can think of as the razer mouse has it's own proprietary drivers.

This all makes me wonder how many people out there are using these cheap mice and experiencing this, but not knowing that it's an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your mouse input is incorrect.
Maybe you want to doublecheck that you get more serious values with another program like

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="Form1">
<textarea  type="text" name="posx" />
</textarea>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var start = Date.now();
document.onmousemove = function (event)
{       
    if (Date.now() - start<10) return;
    start = Date.now();    
    document.Form1.posx.value += start + "\t"+ event.clientX +"\n" ;    
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```